# Binary counter for loop

Tags: java

```
/**
 * Created by abdul on 10/31/2016.
 */
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BitCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter Cases:");
         int cases = in.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        int a = in.nextInt();
        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(a);
        String[] nums = {binary};
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
            if (nums[j].equals("1"))
                count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

This is a problem from Code Abbey Called Bit Count
As you probably know, all values inside a computer are represented in binary system. In this simple task you are to write a program which counts the number of non-zero bits in a given value.

We are using 32-bit integer values, so there should be from 0 to 32 non-zero bits.
http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/bit-count
Could you please help me understand why my loop is only incrementing once and not incrementing through the entire thing?

Comment: `nums.length` is `1`, because there's just one thing in the array.  I think you want `binary.length()` instead.

Comment: [`Integer.bitCount(a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-) could be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You do this:

```
    int a = in.nextInt();
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(a);
    String[] nums = {binary};
```

Let's imagine you enter "4". What happens?

1. First the number 4 gets stored in `a`.
2. Then the string "000100" or something similar gets stored in the string `binary`.
3. Then you create an array with one element, that element is equal to the string `binary`.

What you are trying to do is create an array of each digit of the string, but you actually create a single element array that simply stores another copy of the string you already computed! Try this instead:

```
    int a = in.nextInt();
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(a);
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < binary.length(); j++) {
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
        if (binary.charAt(j) == '1')
            count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

This will check each character of the binary string for the digit 1.